# Running filewatcher as separate process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, daemon, file-watcher

I am still very new to Ruby so I hope you can help. I have a Ruby on Rails app that needs to watch a specific directory "Dir A" to which I keep adding txt files. Once a new file appears it needs to be processed into csv file, which then appears in a tmp directory before being attached to a user, and disappears from tmp after the file goes into ActiveStorage, while keeping the original txt file in "Dir A" for a limited amount of time.

Now, I am using filewatcher gem to watch "Dir A" , however I need it to run on server startup and continue to run in the background. I understand I need to daemonize the process, but how can I do it from *.rb files rather than terminal?
Atm I am using Threads, but I am not sure if that's the best solution...

I also have the following issues:
- how to process files which have already appeared in the folder before the server start up?
- filewatcher does not seem to pick up another new file while it's still processing the previous one, and threads don't seem to help with that
- what would you recommend to be the best way to keep track of processed files - a database, or renaming/copying files into a different folder, or some global variables or maybe there's something else? I have to know which files are processed so I don't repeat the process espacially in cases when I need to schedule filewatcher restarts due to its declining performance (filewatcher documentation states it is best to restart the process if it's been long-running)

I'm sorry to bombard with questions, but I need some guidance, maybe there's a better gem I've missed, I looked at guard gem but I am not entirely sure how it works and filewatcher seemed simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should probably be split into two, one about running `filewatcher` as a background process, and another about managing processed files, but as far as `filewatcher` goes, a simple solution would be to use the `foreman` gem with a Procfile.

You can start your Rails app in one process and filewatcher in another with a Procfile in the root of your app, like this:

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
filewatcher: filewatcher "**/*.txt" "bundle exec rake process_txt_files"
```

and move whatever processing needs to be done into a rake task. With this you could just run `foreman start` locally to start both processes, and if your production server supports Procfiles (like Heroku, for example), this makes it easy to do the same in production.